# (JavaFX) How do I make it so the DirectoryChooser opens once instead of twice and get the data to actually appear in the text file?

Tags: java, arraylist, javafx

I'm using a WindowEvent to open up the directories in order to select a folder for a file to be saved in. When I close the window, therefore executing the WindowEvent, the directories open up and I select a folder. However, the directories open up a second time and I'm finding it hard to understand why. Furthermore, I think I've written the code correctly to fill the created text file but when I look at the text file Titles.txt in the folder after the execution it is empty.

```
@Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        LibraryGUI gui = new LibraryGUI();
        primaryStage.setTitle("Personal Lending Library");
        items.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);
        Scene scene = new Scene(gui.layout(), 325, 340);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(WindowEvent event) {
                try {

                    DirectoryChooser chooser = new DirectoryChooser();
                    chooser.setTitle("Select Folder");
                    File dir = chooser.showDialog(null);
                    if (dir.exists()) {
                        File file1 = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath() + "\\Titles.txt");
                        FileWriter fw1 = new FileWriter(file1);
                        BufferedWriter buffW1 = new BufferedWriter(fw1);
                        for (int i = 0; i < titles.size(); i++) {
                            buffW1.write(titles.get(i));
                            buffW1.newLine();
                        }
                        fw1.close();
                        buffW1.close();
                    } else {

                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

What I expect to happen is the directories window opens up once, a folder can then be selected, and then the created file is populated by the ArrayList and saved to the selected folder. Any help/tips will go a long way. Thanks.

Comment: Can you print the content of the object "event" that is argument of the method handle? maybe there you can difference between the two calls of the method (some variable that is setted in that object)

Comment: I am not getting the DirectoryChooser more than once.  You should close your buffer before your writer and that will solve the writing problem.

Comment: @purringpigeon I found the problem with the DirectoryChooser and now it's only opening once. I did change it to close the buffer before the writer but the file Titles.txt is still empty after adding titles during execution.

Comment: Did you verify that `titles` is not empty when you write its elements?

Comment: @VGR To check that, I just put that code into an if/else statement to check if `!titles.isEmpty()` and it turns out that the ArrayList is indeed empty. This is confusing though because every time a title is added to the list, I print it to the console to make sure it's there. I believe it is automatically erased once I close the window which I can't figure out how to remedy. Thanks for pointing that out to me by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using the Parent Stage instead of using
null in this method showDialog(stage) and this way prevents DirectoryChooser from opening repeatedly.

```
DirectoryChooser directoryChooser = new DirectoryChooser();

// Parent stage
Stage stage = (Stage) anchoriId.getScene().getWindow();

// Set Initial Directory as Documents
directoryChooser.setInitialDirectory(new JFileChooser().getFileSystemView().getDefaultDirectory());

// Select parent stage
selectedFolder = directoryChooser.showDialog(stage);


if (selectedFolder == null) {
     // Get Documents path
     selectedFolder = new JFileChooser().getFileSystemView().getDefaultDirectory().getAbsoluteFile();
}
```